# Why load factor of hashmap in redis is as large as 5

Tags: redis, hashmap, load-factor

In algorithm classes and authorized books, load-factor is smaller than 1 as it is with Java the default is 0.75. But in redis source code, the load factor is 5.

```
54 /* Using dictEnableResize() / dictDisableResize() we make possible to
55  * enable/disable resizing of the hash table as needed. This is very important
56  * for Redis, as we use copy-on-write and don't want to move too much memory
57  * around when there is a child performing saving operations.
58  *
59  * Note that even when dict_can_resize is set to 0, not all resizes are
60  * prevented: a hash table is still allowed to grow if the ratio between
61  * the number of elements and the buckets > dict_force_resize_ratio. */
62 static int dict_can_resize = 1;
63 static unsigned int dict_force_resize_ratio = 5;
```

Why is it?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The load factor to start rehashing is ~1. The `dict_force_resize_ratio` value is a safety measure such that even if rehashing is disabled, once it gets to that load factor it will force it.

You can see this in `_dictExpandIfNeeded(dict *d)` in `dict.c`

```
/* If we reached the 1:1 ratio, and we are allowed to resize the hash
 * table (global setting) or we should avoid it but the ratio between
 * elements/buckets is over the "safe" threshold, we resize doubling
 * the number of buckets. */
if (d->ht[0].used >= d->ht[0].size &&
    (dict_can_resize ||
     d->ht[0].used/d->ht[0].size > dict_force_resize_ratio))
{
    return dictExpand(d, d->ht[0].used*2);
}
```

Redis allows ~1 to start rehashing since the rehashing is not done all at once. It is progressively done by maintaining two hash tables.

See `dict.h`:

```
/* This is our hash table structure. Every dictionary has two of this as we
 * implement incremental rehashing, for the old to the new table. */
typedef struct dictht {
    dictEntry **table;
    unsigned long size;
    unsigned long sizemask;
    unsigned long used;
} dictht;

typedef struct dict {
    dictType *type;
    void *privdata;
    dictht ht[2];
    long rehashidx; /* rehashing not in progress if rehashidx == -1 */
    unsigned long iterators; /* number of iterators currently running */
} dict;
```

And in `dict.c`:

```
/* Performs N steps of incremental rehashing. Returns 1 if there are still
 * keys to move from the old to the new hash table, otherwise 0 is returned.
 *
 * Note that a rehashing step consists in moving a bucket (that may have more
 * than one key as we use chaining) from the old to the new hash table, however
 * since part of the hash table may be composed of empty spaces, it is not
 * guaranteed that this function will rehash even a single bucket, since it
 * will visit at max N*10 empty buckets in total, otherwise the amount of
 * work it does would be unbound and the function may block for a long time. */
int dictRehash(dict *d, int n) {...
```

And there is some additional insight in `redis.conf`, for the `activerehashing` setting.

```
# Active rehashing uses 1 millisecond every 100 milliseconds of CPU time in
# order to help rehashing the main Redis hash table (the one mapping top-level
# keys to values). The hash table implementation Redis uses (see dict.c)
# performs a lazy rehashing: the more operation you run into a hash table
# that is rehashing, the more rehashing "steps" are performed, so if the
# server is idle the rehashing is never complete and some more memory is used
# by the hash table.
#
# The default is to use this millisecond 10 times every second in order to
# actively rehash the main dictionaries, freeing memory when possible.
#
# If unsure:
# use "activerehashing no" if you have hard latency requirements and it is
# not a good thing in your environment that Redis can reply from time to time
# to queries with 2 milliseconds delay.
#
# use "activerehashing yes" if you don't have such hard requirements but
# want to free memory asap when possible.
activerehashing yes
```

Answer (score 1):

Because in Redis, load_factor is calculated by: `ht[0].used/d->ht[0].size`, `used` means the count of elements in the hash table, `size` means only the size of the underlying array, so if hash conflict happens, elements will be stored in a linked list, the size of which is not included in `ht[0].size`.